# php class and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have simple autocomplete JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$( ".autocomplete" ).each(function() {
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: '/php/LiveSearch2.php?name='+ $(this).attr('name') + '&',
        minLength: 1,
        appendTo: "#container"
    }); 
});
});
```

i have written php class to push the values but it is not working. I am making some mistake somewhere. Below is LiveSearch2.php

```
<?php

class swapnil {

private $testname;
public $json;

public function __construct {
    $this->testname = array('swapnil','ranadive');
    $this->json = json_encode($this->testname);
    echo $this->json;

}
}

$Business = new swapnil();
?>
```

when i use php code without class it works fine.

```
<?php
 $testname = array('swapnil', 'ranadive');
 $json = json_encode($testname);

 echo $json
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

After `__construct` the parenthesis are missing. Here try this:

```
 class swapnil {

 private $testname;
 public $json;

 public function __construct() {
  $this->testname = array('swapnil','ranadive');
  $this->json = json_encode($this->testname);
  echo $this->json;

 }
}

$Business = new swapnil();
```

Comment: @SwapnilRanadive Its echoing the data properly. Check your auto complete.

Comment: thanks. Yes, path was incorrect, appreciate your help.

Comment: @SwapnilRanadive Glad to help :)